# How would I partition an array of integers into N number of partitions?

Tags: c++

For instance, I have array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4} and want to partition it into 2 subarrays, so:

subarray1 = {1, 2} and subarray2 = {3, 4}

Is there a way to partition it and create the arrays automatically, depending on the user input for N?

(For background, I am taking an array with 100000 integer values, sorted, and partitioning them so that to find a number that is in the array will be a lot more efficient. Since its sorted and partitioned, I can know their start and end range for each array, and just search there)

Comment: "Depending on the user input for N" of course there's a way. What does N signify though? If you have `int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}`, you can index subarrays like `int* b = a;` and `int* c = a + 2;` But there's likely an STL container that already does what you want, without tricky pointer arithmetic.

Comment: [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) or [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) might come in handy.

Comment: Why not use Binary Search? Its purpose is for searching efficiently in a sorted array. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Comment: I think OP is reinventing binary search

Comment: Do you allow duplicates in the array or does it contain 100000 unique integers? Do the integers have any connection with some other data (in which case you could perhaps use some sort of `map`)? What are the integers representing?

Comment: The integers do not represent anything. I am trying to learn more code and thought of this scenario, and want to learn if it's possible via code to auto partition a sorted array. The integers in each index are randomly generated from [-100000, 100000]

Comment: Ok, so duplicates are allowed then. Well, you can use [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) or a [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) for quick access.

Answer (score -1):

You're asking the wrong question. If you want to find if the number exists in the array, the easiest and fastest way would be to use `std::unordered_set`, the search becomes a constant time operation.

Comment: Search in the STL `std::set` is O(log n) complexity. `std::unordered_set` is constant time.

Comment: If the starting point is an array, copying it to a set just to be able to `find()` a number is a waste of time and RAM. No need to copy anything. `std::binary_search` will do the job.

Comment: Copying into an `std::set` is O(n log n), not linear, and searching is logarithmic, not constant. It's possible to construct a BST from a sorted array in linear time, but I don't think `std::set` supports this.